# Prime NG Customise tool tip on Bar Chart

Tags: angular, chart.js, primeng

I want to customise tool tip on bar chart currently I just want to show total instead of all info on each end point of bar e.g. in the picture I want to show 335 only.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRKxg.png)

```
<p-chart type="bar" [data]="graphData"  [options]="pieOptions10"></p-chart>

this.pieOptions10 = {
  legend: {
      position: 'right',         
  },     
  responsive:true,
  showAllTooltips: true,    
  title: {
    display: true,
    text: 'Product Wise',
    fontSize: 16
  }, 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your graphData, you should add a option labels and put in this the information that you want to show

In Options you have a example: [Chart Documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/v8.2.8-lts/#/chart)

```
this.graphData = {
      labels: "information that you want to show",
      datasets: [
          // your code
       ]

    };
```